# SQL Server 2014 Read json values within an array held in NVARCHAR column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a table with 3 columns:

```
id INT, name NVARCHAR(50), myData NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

`myData` just holds a json string array something like

```
["Fingers"]
["Fingers","Right-"]
["Arm","Fingers","Left-"]
```

I want to select all the values in 1 column, such as

```
Fingers
Fingers
Right-
Arm
Fingers
Left-
```

How can I go about this? I do not believe SQL Server 2014 can read JSON data.

Once this is done, I can select each unique value by doing a `SELECT DISTINCT` statement.

I need to be able to do this with T-SQL, and cannot create any functions to cope with this, must be T-SQL only.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think that's a valid json format?  Doesn't JSON require key:value pairs?

Comment: i think your JSON look like 

`[
{
"Array":
 [
  {"value":"Fingers"},
  {"value":[{"value":"Fingers"},{"value":"Right-"}]},
  {"value":[{"value":"Arm"},{"value":"Fingers"},{"value":"Left-"}]}
 ]
}
]`
.


OPENJSON perfect for your solution for that refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/solve-common-issues-with-json-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#Anchor_6

please look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37218450/6923146

Comment: @HardikMasalawala json supported from SqlServer 2016. Problem is, that we are on 2014 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this, where [#json] is your original table:

```
;with [data] as
(
    select [mydata] = replace(replace(replace([mydata], '[', SPACE(0)), ']', space(0)), '"', space(0)) from [#json]
)
,[split] as
(
    select
        [mydata] = [s].[str]
    from
        [data] as [d]
    cross apply
        (       
            select 
                [str] = [x].[c].[value]('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
            from 
                ( 
                    select [x] = convert(xml, '<i>' + replace([d].[mydata], ',', '</i><i>') + '</i>').[query]('.')
                ) as [a] 
            cross apply 
                [x].[nodes]('i') as [x]([c])
        ) as [s]
)
select 
    [mydata] 
from 
    [split];
```

Full testing query: https://pastebin.com/r4AwxPYS

Comment: This is great.... Just asking.. is it possible without the WITH? Just use a SELECT statement?