# How do I get data from JSON Array MSSQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2016

If I do this I can get the first value in the array. But how can I get all of the values in the list ?

```
SELECT 
    JSON_VALUE('{"Distributor": [5030, 4000, 1231]}', '$.Distributor[0]') AS result;
```

Comment: You should be able to use OPENJSON but I haven't cracked the format yet

Comment: How do you want to display all of the entries in the array? This is an important consideration.

Comment: You can use openjson cobinated with outer apply

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server OPENJSON read nested json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37218254/sql-server-openjson-read-nested-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT value
FROM OPENJSON('{"Distributor": [5030, 4000, 1231]}','$.Distributor')
```

`'$.Distributor'` is the 'start path' to start looking for an array

Answer (score 0):

You can take look at this article: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Using function `Openjson` and `Outer apply`

Example provided:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json =  
N'[  
       { "id" : 2,"info": { "name": "John", "surname": "Smith" }, "age": 25 },  
       { "id" : 5,"info": { "name": "Jane", "surname": "Smith", "skills": ["SQL", "C#", "Azure"] }, "dob": "2005-11-04T12:00:00" }  
 ]'  

SELECT *  
FROM OPENJSON(@json)  
  WITH (id int 'strict $.id',  
        firstName nvarchar(50) '$.info.name', lastName nvarchar(50) '$.info.surname',  
        age int, dateOfBirth datetime2 '$.dob',
    skills nvarchar(max) '$.info.skills' as json) 
    outer apply openjson( skills ) 
                     with ( skill nvarchar(8) '$' )
```

EDIT Code with provided json :

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json = N'{"Distributor": [5030, 4000, 1231]}'

SELECT Distributor
FROM OPENJSON(@json)  
    WITH (Distributors nvarchar(max) '$.Distributor' as json) 
    outer apply openjson( Distributors ) 
                     with ( Distributor int '$' )
```

RESULT :

```
Distributor
5030
4000
1231
```