# SQL Server OPENJSON read nested JSON same key array

Tags: open-json

I am following the idea from [Ed.Schavelev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7289445/ed-schavelev) on article '[SQL Server OPENJSON read nested json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37218254/sql-server-openjson-read-nested-json/41115322#41115322)'. But I need instead of repeating the rows I wanted them (4) to be in the columns. Is this possible?

I have tried as below:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json =   
  N'[  
      
   {
      "EmployeeScheduleXRefCode":"#DF_10212",
      "EmployeeXRefCode":"7274",
      "TimeStart":"2022-10-31T05:30:00",
      "TimeEnd":"2022-10-31T15:30:00",      
      "Published":false,
      "Breaks":[
         
      ],
      "Activities":[
         
      ],
      "Skills":[
         
      ],
      "LaborMetrics":[
         {
            "CodeXRefCode":"MEDIUM",
            "TypeXRefCode":"ACUITY_LM"
         },
         {
            "CodeXRefCode":"ATA",
            "TypeXRefCode":"EMPLOYEE_TYPE_LM"
         },
         {
            "CodeXRefCode":"BM02KR",
            "TypeXRefCode":"TEAM_NAME_LM"
         },
         {
            "CodeXRefCode":"AV_LM",
            "TypeXRefCode":"JOB_TYPE_LM"
         }
      ],
      "Segments":[
         
      ]
   },
   {
      "EmployeeScheduleXRefCode":"#DF_10200",
      "EmployeeXRefCode":"7269",
      "TimeStart":"2022-10-31T05:30:00",
      "TimeEnd":"2022-10-31T15:30:00",      
      "Published":false,
      "Breaks":[
         
      ],
      "Activities":[
         
      ],
      "Skills":[
         
      ],
      "LaborMetrics":[
         {
            "CodeXRefCode":"MEDIUM",
            "TypeXRefCode":"ACUITY_LM"
         },
         {
            "CodeXRefCode":"ATA",
            "TypeXRefCode":"EMPLOYEE_TYPE_LM"
         },
         {
            "CodeXRefCode":"BM01KR",
            "TypeXRefCode":"TEAM_NAME_LM"
         },
         {
            "CodeXRefCode":"AV_LM",
            "TypeXRefCode":"JOB_TYPE_LM"
         }
      ],
      "Segments":[
         
      ]
   }
 ]'  
   
SELECT Shifts.*,LaborMetrics.* FROM  
 OPENJSON ( @json )  
WITH (   
              EmployeeScheduleXRefCode   varchar(200) '$.EmployeeScheduleXRefCode' ,  
              EmployeeXRefCode     varchar(200)     '$.EmployeeXRefCode',
              TimeStart Datetime '$.TimeStart',
              TimeEnd Datetime '$.TimeEnd',
              LaborMetrics nvarchar(max) as json
 ) as Shifts
 cross apply openjson (Shifts.LaborMetrics)
 with
(
    CodeXRefCode nvarchar(100),
    TypeXRefCode nvarchar(100)
) as LaborMetrics
```

But the result is repeating 4 rows and I want them to have them in 4 different columns in a single row.

[image]