# How to read a value from a particular object in a list with JSON string using MS SQL

Tags: json, sql-server, open-json, sql-server-json

```
[{
        "resourceType": "virtualMachines",
        "name": "Standard_E16-4as_v5",
        "tier": "Standard",
        "size": "E16-4as_v5",
        "family": "standardEASv5Family",
        "locations": [
            "SouthAfricaWest"
        ],
        "locationInfo": [
            {
                "location": "SouthAfricaWest",
                "zones": [],
                "zoneDetails": []
            }
        ],
        "capabilities": [
            {
                "name": "MaxResourceVolumeMB",
                "value": "0"
            },
            {
                "name": "vCPUs",
                "value": "16"
            }
        ],
        "restrictions": []
    },
    {
        "resourceType": "virtualMachines",
        "name": "Standard_E15",
        "tier": "Standard",
        "size": "E15",
        "family": "standardEASv5Family",
        "locations": [
            "Africa"
        ],
        "locationInfo": [
            {
                "location": "Africa",
                "zones": [],
                "zoneDetails": []
            }
        ],
        "capabilities": [
            {
                "name": "MaxResourceVolumeMB",
                "value": "25"
            },
            {
                "name": "vCPUs",
                "value": "18"
            },
             
        ],
        "restrictions": []
    }
    ]
```

I What to achieve exactly like this table :

[image]

Need to know how to read a value from a particular object in a list with JSON string using MS SQL
I want to get the values from the above json like the attached table image.

For Example:
In first Object of list has name : "Standard_E16-4as_v5" for that I neeed to know the what's the "MaxResourceVolumeMB" and "vCPUs" value

Comment: What didn't work about your attempt using `OPENJSON`? What *was* that attempt?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server OPENJSON read nested json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37218254/sql-server-openjson-read-nested-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
[
    {
        "resourceType": "virtualMachines",
        "name": "Standard_E16-4as_v5",
        "tier": "Standard",
        "size": "E16-4as_v5",
        "family": "standardEASv5Family",
        "locations": ["SouthAfricaWest"],
        "locationInfo": [
            {
                "location": "SouthAfricaWest",
                "zones": [],
                "zoneDetails": []
            }
        ],
        "capabilities": [
            {
                "name": "MaxResourceVolumeMB",
                "value": "0"
            },
            {
                "name": "vCPUs",
                "value": "16"
            }
        ],
        "restrictions": []
    },
    {
        "resourceType": "virtualMachines",
        "name": "Standard_E15",
        "tier": "Standard",
        "size": "E15",
        "family": "standardEASv5Family",
        "locations": ["Africa"],
        "locationInfo": [
            {
                "location": "Africa",
                "zones": [],
                "zoneDetails": []
            }
        ],
        "capabilities": [
            {
                "name": "MaxResourceVolumeMB",
                "value": "25"
            },
            {
                "name": "vCPUs",
                "value": "18"
            }
        ],
        "restrictions": []
    }
]';

WITH JsonTable AS (
    SELECT 
        JSON_VALUE(value, '$.name') AS VMName,
        JSON_QUERY(value, '$.capabilities') AS Capabilities
    FROM OPENJSON(@json)
    WHERE JSON_VALUE(value, '$.resourceType') = 'virtualMachines'
)

SELECT
    JT.VMName AS Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Cap.name = 'vCPUs' THEN Cap.value ELSE NULL END) AS vCPUs,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Cap.name = 'MaxResourceVolumeMB' THEN Cap.value ELSE NULL END) AS MaxResourceVolumeMB
FROM JsonTable JT
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Capabilities) 
WITH (
    name NVARCHAR(100) '$.name',
    value NVARCHAR(100) '$.value'
) AS Cap
GROUP BY JT.VMName
```

| Name | vCPUs | MaxResourceVolumeMB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Standard_E15 | 18 | 25 |
| Standard_E16-4as_v5 | 16 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8We-u4Gy)

Comment: A *good* answer explains the solution. Also, out of interest, why use `JSON_QUERY` and `JSON_VALUE` and not a `WITH` clause inside the CTE?

Comment: Yes, watch out for JSON_QUERY, is a bit dangerous cause it only supports 4000 characters output so larger jsons becomes NULL, you can instead use AS JSON in the WITH clause to return whole json node to the "next" level

Comment: @Amira Bedhiafi Thanks its working and I have one doubt "For this scenario need to use **group by** clause to group vm name so to accept group by did you used MAX or some others reasons? "

Comment: I have done one simple query based on your input `SELECT
      JSON_VALUE(JT.value, '$.name') as Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Cap.name = 'vCPUs' THEN Cap.value ELSE NULL END) AS vCPUs,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Cap.name = 'MaxResourceVolumeMB' THEN Cap.value ELSE NULL END) AS MaxResourceVolumeMB
FROM openJson(@Json , '$') JT
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JT.value, '$.capabilities') 
WITH (
    name NVARCHAR(100) '$.name',
    value NVARCHAR(100) '$.value'
) AS Cap
GROUP BY JSON_VALUE(JT.value, '$.name')`